# How can I block an IP, if I'm getting many http requests in a second in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-services, bulkinsert, ip-blocking

Making a function that ensure a user is not sending a bulk request and if so then it should be blocked for sometime.

Comment: PHP is the wrong level to do this at.

Comment: That isn't really a good thing to put in PHP due to the way PHP is executed. It's a much better idea to use a stateful firewall to monitor and block abusive traffic.

Comment: what if a script generating recursive legal task?? But those operations are harmful Then what will be the solution??

Answer (score 1):

It's better to do it on the web server and/or OS level. A simple solution to try is [mod_evasive](https://github.com/jzdziarski/mod_evasive) for Apache.

> mod_evasive is an evasive maneuvers module for Apache to provide
>   evasive action in the event of an HTTP DoS or DDoS attack or brute
>   force attack. It is also designed to be a detection tool, and can be
>   easily configured to talk to ipchains, firewalls, routers, and
>   etcetera.

You can do the same with [mod_security](https://www.modsecurity.org/) but it's way more complicated.